# openlayers ol-ext how to exclude features on transform

Tags: openlayers

I have a drawing tool that uses the Transform interaction from ol-ext. Is there a way to exclude certain shapes from the transform? For example, I'd like to exclude transforming a LineString.

```
    transformInteraction = new interaction.Transform({
        features: this.props.drawnShapes, // null at initialization
        layers: map.getLayers().getArray().filter(l => l.get("transformable")),
        hitTolerance: 5,
        translateFeature: true,
        translate: true,
        keepAspectRatio: events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
        rotate: true
    });
```

OR is there a way to set the transformable features after initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `filter` key in `ol.interaction.Transform` object constructor. The excerpt from source code of http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html show you how you can use it to restrict the job to exclude lines.

```js
var interaction = new ol.interaction.Transform (
{ addCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
  // filter: function(f,l) { return f.getGeometry().getType()==='Polygon'; },
  // layers: [vector],
  hitTolerance: 2,
  translateFeature: $("#translateFeature").prop('checked'),
  scale: $("#scale").prop('checked'),
  rotate: $("#rotate").prop('checked'),
  keepAspectRatio: $("#keepAspectRatio").prop('checked') ? ol.events.condition.always : undefined,
  translate: $("#translate").prop('checked'),
  stretch: $("#stretch").prop('checked')
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like i'm going to need to update to 3.0.0. I'm currently on 1.3.3.